# ¿How to create a custom FormRequest from normal Request?

Tags: php, laravel, request, laravel-formrequest

I find something lost...

**The problem**

I need to construct 2 custom FormRequest from 1 normal Request
Let's suppose this fake scenario

First FormRequest

```
StoreClientRequest
```

Second FormRequest

```
UpdateClientRequest
```

On the Controller:

```
public function store(Request $request){
    //Do something...
    $firstRequest = new StoreClientRequest($request);
    $secondRequest = new UpdateClientRequest($request);
}
```

Are there way to make something similar to this fake scenario.

Comment: what are you going to do with these form requests? ... hypothetically

Comment: Each request represents 2 differents parts of an Entity, but, I can`t divide this logic  in 2 different methods, then, I will validate the 2 parts.

Comment: Requests have a static `createFrom` method which takes a Request (from) and another Request (to) [optional]  `createFrom(Request $from, $to = null)` ... technically you could also resolve both of those via method injection (which would cause them both to validate right away)

Comment: But all data is sending by unique form request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to get an instance of your Form Requests, without resolving them from the IoC Container, you could use the `createFrom` method:

```
$firstRequest = StoreClientRequest::createFrom($request);
```

This will make sure it is filled with the same data as `$request`.

Comment: Thanks!!!!!! 

Comment: np, good luck and have fun with Laravel