# Laravel - How to pass a custom array or custom request to a FormRequest?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-formrequest

I need to create a custom request on the fly and pass the request to the Form Request. The closest answer that I found was [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70674906/13933721). However when I run `$request->validated()`, it gives me error message `Call to a member function validated() on null in /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/FormRequest.php:221`.

Below is the whole code:

Function A

```
private $service;

public function __construct(
    Service $service,
) {
    $this->service = $service;
}

...

$data = [
    "variable_a" => "string",
    'variable_b' => true,
];
$request = new Request();
$request->replace($data);
$customFormRequest = new CustomFormRequest();
$validate = $customFormRequest::createFrom(
    $request
);
$return_data = $this->service->project($validate);
```

Service

```
public function project(CustomFormRequest $request)
{
    \Log::debug($request);
    $data = $request->validated();
    \Log::debug($data);
}
```

**Note**
`$request` and `$request->all()` has array values when logging inside Service.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it doesn't work is because you are only getting an instance of the CustomFormRequest. Custom form requests are only validated when they are resolved out of the container.

```
class SomeClass
{
    public function __construct(private Service $service) {}

    public function call()
    {
        $data = [
            'variable_a' => 'string',
            'variable_b' => true,
        ];

        $request = CustomFormRequest::create('', '', $data)
            ->setContainer(app())
            ->validateResolved();

        $return_data = $this->service->project($request);
    }
}

class Service
{
    public function project(CustomFormRequest $request)
    {
        $validated = $request->validated();
        // other stuff
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. Unfortunately, I am unable to change the `CustomFormRequest` since there are a lot of request (via ajax/axios or plain http request) and it works without issues. Plus the project manager has a strict rule of not changing this unless really needed and a lot of other parts of the code benefits on the change. What I did though was create a custom of the CustomFormRequest and changed the `$request->validated()` to `$request->all()` in function `project(CustomFormRequest $request)` for now.

Comment: I know that what I did is not a DRY approach but for now, we will stick to it until we know what the problem is.

Comment: Gotcha. See my edit. The problem is needing to resolve the form request out of the container which automagically runs the validation when resolved. When you resolve it, you can then call methods like ->validated().

Comment: I will try this as soon as I can. Currently in another task. Maybe reply by tomorrow.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Unfortunately, I still have the same error. The code is the same with what I posted but the wrapping of `CustomFormRequest` to `$request` is different.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get back to this to fix my example. See my edit if you are still using $request->all(). Better late than never I suppose.

Comment: Unfortunately I am unable to confirm if this answer works since I already moved on to other projects. Thank you for getting the time to update the answer.